# como hago un contador de hojas en fpdf, osea me muestre el total de las hojas generadas

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{

  public $canthojas;

 
  function Header()
{

  // CONEXION Y DATOS

$hostname_amercado = isset($_SERVER['DB_HOSTNAME']) ? $_SERVER['DB_HOSTNAME'] : "localhost";
$database_amercado = isset($_SERVER['DB_DATABASE']) ? $_SERVER['DB_DATABASE'] : "amremate";
$username_amercado = isset($_SERVER['DB_USER']) ? $_SERVER['DB_USER'] : "root";
$password_amercado = isset($_SERVER['DB_PASSWORD']) ? $_SERVER['DB_PASSWORD'] : "";


$colname_remate = $_POST['remate_num'];
$localid_ex = null;
$provin_ex = null;
$localid_ex2 = null;
$provin_ex2 = null;


// Crear conexión
$amercado = new mysqli($hostname_amercado, $username_amercado, $password_amercado, $database_amercado);
mysqli_set_charset($amercado, "utf8");

$query_lotes = sprintf("SELECT * FROM lotes WHERE codrem = %s ORDER BY codintnum  , codintsublote", $colname_remate);
$lotes = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_lotes) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
$totalRows_lotes = mysqli_num_rows($lotes);

// Leo el remate
$query_remate = sprintf("SELECT * FROM remates WHERE ncomp = %s", $colname_remate);
$remates = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_remate) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
$row_remates = mysqli_fetch_assoc($remates);
$direc = utf8_decode($row_remates["direccion"]);
$fecha = $row_remates["fecreal"];
$hora = $row_remates["horareal"];
$hora = substr($hora,0,5);
$sello = utf8_decode($row_remates["sello"]);
$plazo_sap = utf8_decode($row_remates["plazoSAP"]);
$obs =  utf8_decode($row_remates["observacion"]);
$cod_loc = utf8_decode($row_remates["codloc"]);
$cod_prov = utf8_decode($row_remates["codprov"]);
$fecha         = substr($fecha,8,2)."-".substr($fecha,5,2)."-".substr($fecha,0,4);

$query_provincia = sprintf("SELECT * FROM provincias WHERE codnum = %s", $cod_prov);
$provincia = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_provincia) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
$row_provincia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($provincia);
$provin = utf8_decode($row_provincia["descripcion"]);

$query_localidad = sprintf("SELECT * FROM localidades WHERE codnum = %s", $cod_loc);
$localidad = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_localidad) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
$row_localidad = mysqli_fetch_assoc($localidad);
$localid = utf8_decode($row_localidad["descripcion"]);

//LEO LA TABLA DIR_REMATES PARA VER SI TENGO DIRECCION DE EXPOSICION
$query_dir_remates = sprintf("SELECT * FROM dir_remates WHERE codrem = %s AND secuencia = %d", $colname_remate, 1);
$dir_remates = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_dir_remates) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
$row_dir_remates = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dir_remates);

if ($row_dir_remates != NULL) {

    $dir_direccion =utf8_decode($row_dir_remates["direccion"]);
    $dir_codprov   = utf8_decode($row_dir_remates["codprov"]);
    $dir_codloc    = utf8_decode( $row_dir_remates["codloc"]);

}
// LEO LA SEGUNDA DIRECCION
$query_dir_remates2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM dir_remates WHERE codrem = %s AND secuencia = %d", $colname_remate, 2);
$dir_remates2 = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_dir_remates2) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
$row_dir_remates2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dir_remates2);

if ($row_dir_remates2 != NULL) {
$dir_direccion2 = utf8_decode($row_dir_remates2["direccion"]);
$dir_codprov2   = utf8_decode($row_dir_remates2["codprov"]);
$dir_codloc2    = utf8_decode($row_dir_remates2["codloc"]);
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($dir_remates) > 0 ) {
    $hay_exhib = 1;
    // LEO LA PROVINCIA Y LA LOCALIDAD DE LA DIRECCION DE EXHIBICION
    $query_provincia_ex = sprintf("SELECT * FROM provincias WHERE codnum = %s", $dir_codprov);
    $provincia_ex = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_provincia_ex) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
    $row_provincia_ex = mysqli_fetch_assoc($provincia_ex);
    $provin_ex = utf8_decode($row_provincia_ex["descripcion"]);

    $query_localidad_ex = sprintf("SELECT * FROM localidades WHERE codnum = %s", $dir_codloc);
    $localidad_ex = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_localidad_ex) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
    $row_localidad_ex = mysqli_fetch_assoc($localidad_ex);
    $localid_ex = utf8_decode($row_localidad_ex["descripcion"]);
}
else 
    $hay_exhib = 0;
    
if (mysqli_num_rows($dir_remates2) > 0 ) {
    $hay_exhib = 2;
    // LEO LA PROVINCIA Y LA LOCALIDAD DE LA DIRECCION DE EXHIBICION
    $query_provincia_ex2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM provincias WHERE codnum = %s", $dir_codprov2);
    $provincia_ex2 = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_provincia_ex2) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
    $row_provincia_ex2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($provincia_ex2);
    $provin_ex2 = utf8_decode($row_provincia_ex2["descripcion"]);

    $query_localidad_ex2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM localidades WHERE codnum = %s", $dir_codloc2);
    $localidad_ex2 = mysqli_query($amercado, $query_localidad_ex2) or die(mysqli_error($amercado));
    $row_localidad_ex2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($localidad_ex2);
    $localid_ex2 = utf8_decode($row_localidad_ex2["descripcion"]);
}






// ---------------------------------------------

    // Logo
    $this->Image('images/logo_adrianC.jpg',1,8,65);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    // Movernos a la derecha
    $this->Cell(55);
    // Título
    $this->SetY(7);
    $this->SetX(60);
    $this->Cell(80,10,UTF8_DECODE('CATÁLOGO').' PARA MARTILLERO',0,0,'C');
    // Salto de línea
    $this->Ln(20);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
    $this->SetY(6);
    $this->SetX(135);
    $this->Cell(80,10,'                Olga Cossettini 731, Piso 3 - CABA',0,0,'L');
    $this->SetY(10);
    $this->SetX(135);
    $this->Cell(80,10,'Tel.: (+54) 11 3984-7400 / www.adrianmercado.com.ar',0,0,'L');

    $this->Line(2,18,208,18);

    //========================== HASTA LA LINEA ==========================================

$this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$this->SetY(17);
$this->SetX(5);
$this->Cell(19,10, 'Por c/o de: ',0,0,'L');
$this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$this->Cell(25,10, substr($obs,0,90),0,0,'L');
//=============================================================================
if ( strcmp(substr($hora,3,2) , "00") == 0)
    $hora = substr($hora,0,2);
$this->SetY(22);
$this->SetX(5);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$this->Cell(20,10,'Fecha y Hora: ',0,0,'L');
$this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$dia = ucwords(strftime("%A", strtotime($fecha)));
$mes = ucwords(strftime("%B", strtotime($fecha)));

$dianum = strftime("%d", strtotime($fecha));
if ($dianum[0]==0)
    $dianum = $dianum[1];

$this->Cell(20,10, '    '.$dia.' '.$dianum.' de '.$mes.' de '.strftime("%Y", strtotime($fecha)).' - '.$hora.' hs.',0,0,'L');
//$pdf->Cell(20,10, '      '.$fecha_hoy.' - '.$hora.' hs.',0,0,'L');
//=============================================================================
if ($hay_exhib == 0) {
    $this->SetY(27);
    $this->SetX(5);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    if ($colname_remate == 2272 || $colname_remate == 2271)
        $this->Cell(10,10,'Subasta: ',0,0,'L');
    else
        $this->Cell(20,10,'Subasta / '.utf8_decode('Exhibición').': ',0,0,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $this->Cell(16);
    $this->Cell(120,10,$direc.", ".$localid.", ".$provin,0,0,'L');
    $this->SetX(90);
}
//=============================================================================
if ($hay_exhib == 1) {
    $this->SetY(27);
    $this->SetX(5);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Cell(10,10,'Subasta: ',0,0,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $this->Cell(6);
    $this->Cell(120,10,$direc.", ".$localid.", ".$provin,0,0,'L');
    
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->SetY(32);
    $this->SetX(5);
    $this->Cell(15,10,''.utf8_decode('Exhibición').': ',0,0,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $this->Cell(5);
    $this->Cell(120,10,$dir_direccion.", ".$localid_ex.", ".$provin_ex,0,0,'L');
    $this->SetX(90);
    $this->SetY(37);
}
if ($hay_exhib == 2) {
    $this->SetY(27);
    $this->SetX(5);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->Cell(10,10,'Subasta: ',0,0,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $this->Cell(6);
    $this->Cell(120,10,$direc.", ".$localid.", ".$provin,0,0,'L');
    
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->SetY(32);
    $this->SetX(5);
    $this->Cell(20,10,''.utf8_decode('Exhibición').' 1/2: ',0,0,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $this->Cell(6);
    $this->Cell(120,10,$dir_direccion.", ".$localid_ex.", ".$provin_ex,0,0,'L');
    $this->SetX(90);
    $this->SetY(37);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $this->SetY(37);
    $this->SetX(5);
    $this->Cell(20,10,''.utf8_decode('Exhibición').' 2/2: ',0,0,'L');
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $this->Cell(6);
    $this->Cell(120,10,$dir_direccion2.", ".$localid_ex2.", ".$provin_ex2,0,0,'L');
    $this->SetX(90);
    $this->SetY(42);
}



if ($sello=='1') {
  $this->SetX(10);
  if ($hay_exhib == 0)
    $this->SetY(37);
  if ($hay_exhib == 1)
    $this->SetY(42);
  if ($hay_exhib == 2)
    $this->SetY(47);
  $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
  $this->Cell(25);
  $this->Cell(140,7,'Venta sujeta a '.utf8_decode('aprobación').' por la empresa vendedora '.$plazo_sap,1,0,'C');
}

$this->Ln(35);

$this->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
//Bold Font for Field Name
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
$this->SetY(42);
$this->SetX(4);
$this->Cell(16,10,'LOTE',1,0,'C',1);
$this->SetX(20);
$this->Cell(150,10,'DESCRIPCION',1,0,'C',1);
$this->SetX(170);
$this->Cell(34,10,'P. BASE',1,0,'C',1);
$this->Ln();
}


    public function contPage()
    {
        parent::AddPage();
        $this->canthojas++;
    }

    // Método para obtener el contador de páginas
    public function getPageCount()
    {
        return $this->canthojas;
    }


// Pie de página
function Footer()
{
    // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    $this->getPageCount();
    // Número de página
    


    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/'.$this->canthojas, 0, 0, 'C');

    
}
```

necesito hacer que me cuente la cantidad de hojas que genero y me muestre en el footer 1/4 en el caso de que sean 4 hojas generadas.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente tenes que usar:

- El método [PageNo](http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/pageno.htm)

  > Devuelve el número de página actual.
- El método [AliasNbPages](http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/pageno.htm)

  > Define un alias para el número total de páginas. Se sustituira en el momento que el documento se cierre.
  > El alias por defecto es `{nb}`.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Footer()
    {
        // Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Select Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);
        // Print current and total page numbers
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
    }
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
```

Comment: $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C'); lo tengo así ahora pero me muestra en la primera pagina: 1/{nb}  ,  en la segunda 2/{nb} y así

Comment: @LucianoNahuelGimenezAusfet, Disculpa, me olvide de señalar que tenes que inicializar el alias usando `$this->AliasNbPages();`. Ya actualice mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no puedo dar punto a favor porque tengo menos de 15 de reputación, gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Luciano, ya tienes mas de 15 :)... Y adicionalmente puedes aceptar la respuesta con el check que está bajo los botones de votos